# TypeScript 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function that accepts a value (e.g. `number`) and a callback that maps that value to another value, and the function just applies that callback:

```
function mapNumber<T>(value: number, mapfn: (value: number) => T) {
  return mapfn(value);
}
```

I want to provide `identity` as the default argument for the callback in case the user does not provide it:

```
function identity<T>(x: T) {
  return x;
}
    
// Error: Type '<T>(x: T) => T' is not assignable to type '(value: number) => T'.
  // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
   // 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'
function mapNumber<T>(value: number, mapfn: (value: number) => T = identity) {
  return mapfn(value);
}
```

Any idea why this is a problem? By my reasoning, since `mapfn` is in the contravariant position, it should accept any callback that's more general than `(value: number) => T`, so `identity` should work?

Comment: Assume the following call: `mapNumber<string>(1)`. There's nothing wrong with denying such calls instead, but it's much more work for compiler. And they definitely could've improved this error message text.

Comment: ^ That’s the issue, yes.  Do you want to write an answer post? OP, would such an answer be acceptable to you?

Comment: I see, thanks, yeah that makes sense. I guess I got so used to generics being inferred that I didn't consider that.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the issue is that with your code you would be able to define `T` to be something other than a number, which would cause your `identity` function to be of the wrong type for `mapfn` since `identity` returns the same time it receives, which in this case is `number`, and therefore not the expected type `T`.

In the example `mapNumber<string>(10)` the type parameter `T` is `string`, but `mapfn` (using `identity`) returns `number`, not `string`.

One way to fix this is by casting `identity` as `any`, which will remove the error from your `mapNumber` function definition. However this still allows for the issue above without giving a warning, which can lead to bugs further down in your code.

Instead, I would recommend overloading the definition of `mapNumber` so that there is a special case for `T = number` and only in this case is `mapfn` optional.

```
function identity<T>(x: T) {
    return x;
}

function mapNumber(value: number, mapfn?: (value: number) => number): number;
function mapNumber<T>(value: number, mapfn: (value: number) => T): T;
function mapNumber<T>(value: number, mapfn: (value: number) => T = identity as any) {
    return mapfn(value);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
// allowed:
mapNumber(10)
mapNumber(10, (x) => x * 10)
mapNumber(10, (x) => x.toString())
mapNumber<string>(10, (x) => x.toString())

// not allowed:
mapNumber<string>(10)
```

Note that we still have the `any` cast but that's just for the types to work on the base signature of `mapNumber`—`identity` will only be used as a default value, which is only possible with the first overload signature (when `T` is `number`).

Comment: Great, thanks, I haven't thought of overloading, this looks like a nice solution!